# Use a filter statement in JSON call on Web API with Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

We got a Web API webservice with entity framework and accept JSON calls.

We have a call named: GetResidents which lists all residents.  We would like to have an extra parameter (hash) which allows the caller to filter the results on the server.

Like this:

```
{"filter":{
      "and":{
         "age":{
            "less_than":80,
            "greater_than":60
            }
         },
         {
           "active":{
           "eq":true
           }
         }
```

In RoR in the past I've used this gem which works great: https://github.com/QutBioacoustics/baw-server/wiki/Rails-API-Spec:-Filtering  Does something similar exist in WebAPI?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Use OData. Here is documentation [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options). Basic example:

```
public class ResidentsController : ApiController
{
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<Resident> GetResidents() {}
}
```

For your json:

```
http://localhost/api/residents?$filter=age lt 80 and age gt 60 and active eq true
```